# Podio curl calls getting unauthorized error even with app token

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, podio

I'm trying to get familiar with the Podio API by initially retrieving items from an existing app. Ultimately, my use-case is to read/write items for a team whose needs have scaled into the realm of automation.

Authenticating as an app, I've successfully obtained an auth token from https://api.podio.com/oauth/token with `"scope": "space_3190207:all"`

However, all my curl calls fail with a 401
   `"error_description": "invalid_request", "error": "unauthorized"`

for example:
`curl --request POST \ --url 'https://api.podio.com/item/app/<APP_ID>/filter?Authorization=OAuth2%20<TOKEN>'`

I'm totally new to the Podio API, so I may have some core misunderstandings. I tried digging into the workings of the pypodio2 lib, but that's long outdated. Other info:

I'm pretty sure the URL path is right; there's a different error when it's not.

The "API Key Generator" required a full domain. I've never used an API that required this, and am not sure what it's for (callback URL?), so I just used my gitlab domain.

Thanks!

I've tried using the token returned from the "app" grant_type, as well as the global-scoped token from the "password" type.

I've tried several "get info" operations (not post or edit); all fail with the "unauthorized" error. I also tried the pypodio2 Python lib, but that won't even compile and hasn't been updated in 7 years.

I also tried fiddling with GET vs POST, adding content-type JSON header, and getting new tokens from the podio auth endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already returned the auth token, you need to use that within the header instead of the url:

```
curl https://api.podio.com/item/app/<APP_ID>/filter
     -X POST 
     -H Authorization: Basic <access_token>
     -d '{"filters" : {<field_id> : <search_string>}}'
```